# Area of parallelogram for 4 dimensional vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, area

[image: Question image here]

Hello, basically I just don't understand its explanation.

I also do not know what kind of formula it is used.. (It does look like it used some kinda formula)

Thank you very much if you can explain it well!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the formula to use:

$||a||^2*||b||^2 - |a.b|^2$.

Which is the magnitude of a^2, magnitude of b^2 subtract the dot product of a.b^2.

Comment: Also square root the entire equation

Comment: Very good answer. This formula is applicable for any 2 Vectors in any Dimension

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Calculate the length of these two vectors and find the angle between them using inner product. After getting the height use the [area formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram#Area_formula).

Answer (score 2):

There is a theorem which states that if you have $m$ vectors in $R^n$, then the $m$-volume of the $m$-parallepiped defined by those vectors is $\sqrt{det(A^T A)}$ where $A$ is a matrix whose columns are the $m$ vectors.

In this case, $m=2$ and $n=4$.

Comment: Welcome on the MathSE! Note, the site supports Latex formatting, just write `$\sqrt{\det A^T}$` and you will get $\sqrt{\det A^T}$.

Comment: Fantastic Answer. I have verified using MS excel

Comment: Can anybody link a reference for this formula? Thank you!

Comment: Well, I have found this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1882451/601797

Comment: What is this theorem called?

Comment: det A^T = det A, so why bother with sqrt(x^2), why isn't the answer |det A|??